# ¿Cómo hacer un parámetro por referencia en C#?

Tags: c#, objeto, parametros

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            //Metodo de instancia que devuelva valor
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
            Nombre nombre1 = new Nombre();
            string nombre = "RAMSES";
            nombre1.persona(ref nombre);
            Console.WriteLine(nombre);
            

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    class Nombre
    {
        public string persona(ref string name)
        {
            name = "Jose";
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            return name;
        }
    }
```

Saludos, he estado buscando en internet pero no he encontrado lo que se me pide: lo que se supone que debo hacer es que a la hora de ejecutar el método Main aparezca en consola "RAMSES", pero en vez de eso me aparece dos veces "Jose", vi en un video de yt como un hombre hacia algo semejante pero con un método static, trate de aplicarlo en este método instancia pero no me funciona ¿Cómo resuelvo eso?

Comment: El código por referencia está correcto. Cuando llamas el método `persona()` el nombre "RAMSES" se cambia por "Jose".  No sé en qué te estás confundiendo.

Comment: Tienes razón, yo tuve una confusión porque esperaba que saliera "RAMSES" en la consola y salía "JOSE", yo lo que hice fue poner Ramses en el metodo persona para que entonces me salga en consola, gracias por la ayuda.